# counting the number of files being copied

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am interested in modifying a bash script file whose purpose is to copy large amount of files to destination path. What i'm trying to achieve is count the number of files as they are being copied.
How can i achieve the objective state above ?

Comment: It would be nice if you could take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your file names do not contain a newline.

```
cp -v file* targetdir | cat -n
```

Output:

```
     1 `file_123.png' -> `targetdir/file_123.png'
     2 `file_207.txt' -> `targetdir/file_207.txt'
     3 `file_44.png' -> `targetdir/file_44.png'
```

---

or only numbers (GNU sed):

```
cp -v file* targetdir | sed -n '/.*/='
```

Comment: does not work if you want to copy a whole directory to a target directory.

Comment: Cyrus - assuming gnu `cp`, it doesn't matter if there are newlines in file names as they're quoted so the `wc` is always right.

Comment: the objective is to copy the content of a directory into a target directory recursively, such that as the content of the directory "files" is being copied , the output of the command is written to a variable.

Comment: @SamGomari: `cp -Rv sourcedir/* targetdir | cat -n` should do the job.

Comment: @Cyrus  I did the -av , and it worked . Thanks